# Transformar galeria vertical em horizontal

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma galeria na vertical e eu gostaria de colocar na horizontal, como eu faço isso?

```css
#gallery {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  list-style-type:none; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  width:320px; 
  height:425px; 
  border:1px solid #888; 
  background:#ffffff;
}
#gallery li {
  float:left;
}
#gallery li a {
  display:block; 
  height:30px;
  width:320px; 
  float:left; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff; 
  cursor:default;
}
#gallery li a img {
  width:320px; 
  height:30px; 
  border:0;
}
#gallery li a:hover {
  background:#eee; 
  height:239px;
}
#gallery li a:hover img {
  height:239px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/ferandomae.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/187.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/pessoa-10-anos.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/Pessoa_1894.gif"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Poste seu HTML também

Comment: Seu código está estranho. Você setou uma altura e largura pequena para o `#gallery` e ainda setou como `overflow: hidden;`... O `#gallery` não devia ser `width: 100%; height: auto;`?

Comment: O que você tentou? No Stack Ovreflow americano tem uma dúzia dessas perguntas.

Comment: Você pode adicionar no `#gallery li {display:inline}` e tirar o `display:block #gallery li a`, não vai ficar 100% ainda mas... acho que deve ser algo parecido que você gostaria não é? Eu tiraria o :hover de aumentar a imagem e faria eventos .on('click') jquery para abrir em um modal a imagem maior... acho que traria uma experiência melhor ao usuário;

Comment: @Rafael Withoeft Meta aqui o código que você alteraria.

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre você usa bootstrap?

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre você precisa mesmo aumentar a imagem ao passar o mouse?  e esse link ali na tag a, representaria o álbum algo do tipo? poderia ser tirado e colocado em outro lugar por exemplo?

Comment: Use #Gallerry ul li{display:inline;  float:left}

Answer (score 1):

Basta definir a largura do #gallery para 1280px (320px cada imagem x 4 imagens) e defini a altura para ser a mesma das imagens quando estão em :hover.

```css
#gallery {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  list-style-type:none; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  width:1280px; 
  height:239px; 
  border:1px solid #888; 
  background:#ffffff;
}
#gallery li {
  float:left;
}
#gallery li a {
  display:block; 
  height:30px;
  width:320px; 
  float:left; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff; 
  cursor:default;
}
#gallery li a img {
  width:320px; 
  height:30px; 
  border:0;
}
#gallery li a:hover {
  background:#eee; 
  height:239px;
}
#gallery li a:hover img {
  height:239px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/ferandomae.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/187.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/pessoa-10-anos.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="imagens/Pessoa/Galeria/Pessoa_1894.gif"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elabourei uma maneira mais responsiva para seu modelo. Ao invés de definir o tamanho da imagem, há um "corte" delas, pois assim elas não ficam distorcidas.

Usei imagens exemplos. Da maneira que está basta se colocar o seu `min-width` desejado na `div#gaalleryBox` (div em que está seu `ul#gallery`) e todos os outros elementos se adequarão.

Como o `width` está em 100% ele ficará do tamanho total da tela inicialmente.

```css
#galleryBox{
  width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
  /* min-width: 500px; Mude para o que você deseja */
}
#gallery {
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  width:100%; 
  border:1px solid #888; 
  background:#ffffff;
}
#gallery li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
}
#gallery li a{
  display: inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width: 100%; 
  float:left; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff; 
  cursor:default;
  overflow: hidden;  
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
#gallery li a img {
  width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
  border:0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -30%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;


}
#gallery li a:hover {
  background:#eee; 
  height:auto;
}
#gallery li a:hover img{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="galleryBox">
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="http://goo.gl/T3W9x1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="http://goo.gl/ggDsri"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="http://goo.gl/PA6N6T"></a></li>
    <li><a href="vida.html"><img src="http://goo.gl/nNv21c"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```